# C S_ISDIR function misfunctioning

Tags: c

I've written a script in C, to travel between directories. The aim of the program is to visit every folder except the first folder's parents. For example if I started at point C://Program Files, it shouldn't go to C://

But in Program Files folder, all of the folders are accepted to this if function

```
if (!S_ISDIR(buffer.st_mode) && (stat(dir->d_name, &buffer) != -1)
```

But in fact it is true that the file is a folder.

If the folder is a folder I go into this function:

```
 else if (S_ISDIR(buffer.st_mode)) {
 if (strcmp(dir->d_name,".") != 0 && strcmp(dir->d_name, "..") != 0)
```

and go over the function again recursively.

Do you see any error?

Comment: FYI, `if` is not a function.

Comment: Are you reusing the `stat` buffer? You are first testing the `buffer.st_mode` member and only then calling `stat` which is supposed to fill it... Am I missing something?